# Error al generar el APK después de instalar Background Geolocation - IONIC 4

Tags: ionic, ionic3

**estoy usando Ionic 4**

he realizado la instalación del plugin de **Background Geolocation**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation

y después de la instalación simplemente he ejecutado las siguientes lineas

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@alpha
npm install @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

Como se puede comprobar nada fuera de lo normal, pues después de acabar la instalación sin modificar ningún tipo de archivo ejecuto el siguiente comando para generar el APK.

```
ionic cordova build android
```

y me da error y antes de instalar el Background Geolocation me generaba el APK correctamente, adjunto capturas de los errores.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora ejecuto **cordova build android --verbose** para que me de más información y dice lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a mí también me da un error parecido, pero yo lo estoy ejecutando bajo Windows 10. ¿Podría ser un problema el sistema operativo?

Answer (score 0):

Tenia exactamente el mismo error, antes de instalar el `Background Geolocation` generaba el APK correctamente. Te recomiendo no usar por ahora android 8 y ve a la segura con android 7. Prueba instalando el plugin de la siguiente manera:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@2
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3
```

Answer (score 0):

Dice que hay un error con un Resource, y meciona algo de un icon ... para solucionar este problema , debes en la carpeta resources agregar el icono con la extencion icon.png y en el config.xml dentr de platform name="android" agregas esta linea.

luego cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
cordova build android

esto deberia solucinarte, a mi me funciono.